# How do I find the most and least guessed numbers in an array of random numbers in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, jython

I just have to find the most and least guessed numbers in an array of random numbers in python. Here is my code by far:

```
import time
import random
random.seed()

def breakPIN(num):
  end = 0
  list = []
  for i in range(0,9999):
    list.append(random.randint(0,9999))
  printNow(list)  
  if (num == 4):
    end =9999
  elif (num == 6):
    end=999999
  p2b=random.randint(0,9999)

  time1=time.time()

  num=random.randint(0,end)
  while (num!=p2b):
    num=random.randint(0,end)
  list[num]=list[num]+1
  time2=time.time()
  lowest=list[i]
  for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if(lowest > list[i]):
      lowest=list[i]
  printNow(lowest)
  highest=list[i]
  for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if(highest<list[i]):
      highest=list[i]
  printNow(highest)
  return time2-time1


times=[]
for i in range(0,10):
  times.append(breakPIN(6))

sum=0
for i in range(0,len(times)):
  sum = sum + times[i]
printNow(sum/len(times))
printNow(times)
```

As you can tell I can already find the largest number as well as the smallest numbers guessed. Any pointers as to how I can find the most and least guessed numbers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To find the most and the least guessed numbers you could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import random
from collections import Counter


def most_least_guessed(elements):
    counts = Counter(elements)

    most_guessed, _ = counts.most_common(1)[0]
    least_guessed, _ = counts.most_common()[-1]

    return most_guessed, least_guessed


random.seed(42)
lst = []
for i in range(0, 9999):
    lst.append(random.randint(0, 9999))

most, least = most_least_guessed(lst)

print(most, least)
```

**Output**

```
1106 9998
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the most and least guessed numbers you need to know how many times each number was guessed.  Once you know how many times each one was guessed you can just find the min and max.

To record how many times each number was guessed you will need an array that is the same length as the count of available numbers.

This is called a histogram.